# robolectric with gradle: package does not exist when using play-services

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, robolectric

I want to write a unit test where the class to be tested uses at some places play-services. So far I could not make it work.

I am using gradle and my build.gradle file looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

String[][] allowedFlavorCombinations = [
        ...
];

android.variantFilter { variant ->
    boolean buildVariant = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < allowedFlavorCombinations.length; i++) {
        if(allowedFlavorCombinations[i][0].equalsIgnoreCase(variant.getFlavors().get(0).name)
                && allowedFlavorCombinations[i][1].equalsIgnoreCase(variant.getFlavors().get(1).name)) {
            buildVariant = true;
        }
    }
    variant.setIgnore(!buildVariant);
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode=139
        versionName="3.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each  { output ->
                    output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (project.hasProperty('storeFile') &&
            project.hasProperty('storePassword') &&
            project.hasProperty('keyPassword')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(storeFile)
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePassword
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPassword
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keyAlias
    } else {
        buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }

    flavorDimensions "client", "settings"

    productFlavors {
        ...
    }
}

sourceSets {
    unitTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/res')
    }
}

configurations {
    unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
    unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:21.0.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])

    unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/testbase/debug/")
    ...
    unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    unitTestCompile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    unitTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3:jar-with-dependencies') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
    unitTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.8'
    unitTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
    unitTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.1'
    unitTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.1'
    unitTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.1'
    unitTestCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    unitTestCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    unitTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    unitTestCompile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.5'
    unitTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])

    instrumentTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    instrumentTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3:jar-with-dependencies') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}

task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: [assembleDefault, ':AndroidUtilitiesLibrary:unitTest', ':AndroidUraLibrary:unitTest']) {
    testClassesDir = project.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = project.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
}
check.dependsOn unitTest
```

Furthermore there is a topleve build.gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
           jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
           jcenter()
    }
}
```

In my test class I merely try to create an instance of the class to be tested:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;
import org.robolectric.util.ActivityController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ConnectionCallbacks;


@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml",emulateSdk = 18)
public class MyClass Test {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyClass adapter = new MyClass(Robolectric.application, false);

        //TODO
    }

}
```

Running the test I get the following message:

```
error: package com.google.android.gms.common.api does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ConnectionCallbacks;
```

Does someone have some experience in testing classes that use play-services with robolectric (using gradle)?

Comment: any luck? did you fix it? I have same issue